# Java: represent a color image as an array of gray scale intensity values

Tags: java, image, image-processing, grayscale

Is there a built-in utils to represent a color (or gray scale image) as an array of the gray scale intensity values?

If not, suppose I have a `BufferedImage img`, how can I represent this image as an array like this:

```
int[][] intensity = toIntensity(img);
```

How should the toIntensity() method look like?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it without doing your toIntensity() thing:

```
public static BufferedImage convertToType(BufferedImage sourceImage, int targetType) {
        BufferedImage image;
        if (sourceImage.getType() == targetType) {
            image = sourceImage;
        }else {
            image = new BufferedImage(sourceImage.getWidth(), sourceImage.getHeight(), targetType);
            image.getGraphics().drawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, null);
        }
        return image;
    }
```

Call this method with the targetType as: `BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY`
If you need it in another type you can then convert it back and it will retain its gray color.

Answer (score 0):

toIntensity method could be something like this

```
public int[][] toIntensity(BufferedImage img){
        int[][] cols = new int[img.getWidth()][img.getHeight()];
            for(int z = 0;z < img.getWidth();z++){
                for(int a = 0;a < img.getHeight();a++){
                    int color = img.getRGB(z, a);
                    cols[z][a] = color;
                }
            }
            return cols;
        }
```

Comment: What if the image is color image?